# Android app doesn't run on some devices

Tags: android

I have implemented a small android app. It works fine on my test phones: Galaxy S3 Mini (with CyanogenMod), HTC Sense (with Lollipop) and some Xperia phones after normal `.apk` installation. However, after attempting to install it on Galaxy S5 and Galaxy Tab, it crashed with prompt: `invalid application package`.

The target sdk is 21 and the minimum is 14.

Comment: What is the error it is showing in logcat

Comment: how can i get logcat error after installing it by deployed version `.apk` file?

Comment: i dont have those phones near me, i have sent app to my friends to check and they couldnt install it - as i said before i was able to install it on some phones, but not on the others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to clear your Google Play's data and cache.

**Steps:**

1-Go your device's Settings menu.

2-Go to Applications (may also be labeled Application Manager).

3-Tab over to All Applications.

4-Open the Google Play Store app.

5-Tap on Clear Data and Clear Cache.

6-Relaunch Google Play and install or update the our app again.

[checkout this.](https://support.mapmyfitness.com/hc/en-us/articles/200117904-Google-Play-Store-Package-File-is-Invalid-Error-When-Trying-to-Download-the-App)

Comment: all right, this solution worked with Galaxy S5, gonna try it on tablet also, but i think the outcome will be the same